# How to manage exception information across modules in c# background job

Tags: c#, .net, exception, static, console-application

I have a requirement of writing background job in c#.net wherein at any given point of time of exception occurs we need to update error information in database table.

For this requirement I understand that I will need one object which is available across the modules I have created. Why because I am actually processing files on particular location and if during processing anything goes wrong I want to insert a record in database with FileId, FileName information and that's why I always need this information available across all of my modules.

Please refer image for better clarity. [image]

I have modules created as below

1. CDU.CommonDataUpload(Class library) has program.Cs
2. CDU.CommonDataUploaderService module which is again a class library project where I handle all business logic
3. CDU.Infrastructure is my database Class library project where I handle all database operations.

I am calling #2 and #3 from program.cs as per my need and also all exception handling responsibility is in Program.Cs. Other modules(#2 and #3) will throw an exception and my main Module will handle it.

Now I have 2 options and I want to know weather they are the best options or there is any better option to handle it.

1. Use Static Object and share it across all modules and keep updating error information always and if exception occurs use it to dump data in database in catch block
2. I should maintain my own instance in program.cs and pass it across modules  and return it and manage same way in all modules in all functions and if exception occurs use it’s current state to dump data in database in catch block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my personal experience you should maintainence your code within handling exception
because if you catch error and you dont nothing the stack is truncate and exception trace it lost.

Remember catch exception has a cost and it is high

First define modules where maybe should be ocurry exception somethings and if it the program should catch it. example like web.api, calling external library, os system call it could failed in some time

define module with no handling excepcion something like rep.GetUser(), action.GenerateInvoice().. it should always it working

in the first case

the module should envolve an exception handling and log for review and it should return if can or not done the job (if is requiered for continue)

the second case

simple no handling

now in the highest top for the service

MainService.cs

```
void DoAllActivitiesForHere()
{
    try
   {
     ..........
   } 
   catch(exception ex)
  {
    Log.LogException(ex)
  }
}
```

> *TimeStamp: ---
>
> LogType: Exception
>
> message : ex.Message  + GetFullLog(ex.InnerException)
>
> trace = ex.StackTrace.ToString()*

With that information you now know where the exception is happening (stack trace)
if the exception  is more deep like other assemblies you now has the log with the inner exceptions (message) if you log has type you know can apply filter for detect issues.

Comment: Thank you carlos for your reply. I have edited my question. however I am sending you missing part here as well.

I am actually processing files on particular location and if during processing anything goes wrong I want to insert a record in database with FileId, FileName information and that's why I always need this information available across all of my modules. Now I just don't want to know which module it was but I want to know the processing information as mentioned above.

Comment: when i created a program for interface between two systems my applications sent regularly information. Now in each package handling error was added if one package failed iit generate an database log information and save state also register execution counter and after x fails is cancelled recurrence. from that try..ca.. all internal call dont have error hadling. it is for detect where error it raised